# how to remove the white space of invisiable axes in matplotlib during active plot?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to completely remove white space around my axes during active plot (not save_fig as others asked). 
Here we cannot use `bbox_inches='tight'`. I can use tight_layout(pad=0).
When axis is on, it works fine, it shows all the ticks and x-y labels. 
[image: visible axes]
However, in some cases, I set the axis off. What I expected is to see the contents expand to fill up the empty space where the axes are. However, this does not work. It still keep the padding as there are still x-y labels and axes.
[image: invisible axes]
How can I remove the white space of invisible axes objects?
[image: expected result]
**edit:**

I am aware that I can use `ax.set_yticks([])` and `ax.set_xticks([])` to turn those off. But this is clumsy, I have to remember the the ticks before I clear them. And if I remove-then-add those ticks. The ticks cannot automatically update any more.
I wonder is there any more straightforward way to do this?

We can still see there is a small border spacing even after removing all ticks. If someone can come up a way to remove that too. It will be fantastic.

I would also like to keep the title if there is one. Thus the hard-coded `ax.set_position([0,0,1,x])` is not very good for this usage. Surely we can still try to get the top spacing when there is a title, but if someone can provide a more direct/simple way to handle this, it will be preferred.

Example code:

```
def demo_tight_layout(w=10, h=6, axisoff=False, removeticks=False):

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_facecolor((0.8, 0.8, 0.8))
    rect = patches.Rectangle((-w/2, -h/2), w, h, color='#00ffff', alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.plot([-w/2,w/2], [-h/2,h/2])
    ax.plot([-w/2,w/2], [h/2,-h/2])
    ax.set_ylabel("ylabel")
    ax.margins(0)
    _texts = []
    if axisoff:
        ax.set_axis_off()
        _texts.append("axisoff")
    if removeticks:
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_ylabel("")
        _texts.append("removeticks")
    fig.text(0.5, 0.6, " ".join(_texts))

    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
    plt.show()
    return fig, ax, text
```

Comment: Mind that it's always hard to grasp a problem if it's only described. Instead why not create a [mcve] that would show the issue?

Comment: Are you running this as script or in the console, or are you using inline plotting in e.g. a jupyter notebook? Each case would probably have its own optimal solution.

Comment: console/script. No need to optimize for jupyter

Answer (score 2):

You may adjust the subplot parameters depending on whether you turned the axis off or not.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches

def demo_tight_layout(w=10, h=6, axisoff=False):

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_facecolor((0.8, 0.8, 0.8))
    rect = patches.Rectangle((-w/2, -h/2), w, h, color='#00ffff', alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.plot([-w/2,w/2], [-h/2,h/2])
    ax.plot([-w/2,w/2], [h/2,-h/2])
    ax.set_ylabel("ylabel")
    ax.margins(0)
    _texts = []

    fig.tight_layout()
    if axisoff:
        ax.set_axis_off()
        _texts.append("axisoff")
        params = dict(bottom=0, left=0, right=1)
        if ax.get_title() == "":
            params.update(top=1)
        fig.subplots_adjust(**params)

    fig.text(0.5, 0.6, " ".join(_texts))

    plt.show()
```

Now `demo_tight_layout(axisoff=True)` produces

[image]

and `demo_tight_layout(axisoff=False)` produces

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the axes position to fill the figure. If you create your figure and plot with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(some_x_data, some_y_data)
```

you need to add the following line to fill the figure with the axes:

```
ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1], which='both')
```

This sets the axes location relative to the figure size in the following way:

```
[left, bottom, width, height]
```

So to completely fill the figure use `[0, 0, 1, 1]` as shown above.

So taking your code, it should look like this (using `fill_figure` bool to check):

```
def demo_tight_layout(w=10, h=6, axisoff=False, removeticks=False, fill_figure=False):

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_facecolor((0.8, 0.8, 0.8))
    rect = patches.Rectangle((-w/2, -h/2), w, h, color='#00ffff', alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.plot([-w/2,w/2], [-h/2,h/2])
    ax.plot([-w/2,w/2], [h/2,-h/2])
    ax.set_ylabel("ylabel")
    ax.margins(0)
    _texts = []
    if axisoff:
        ax.set_axis_off()
        _texts.append("axisoff")
    if removeticks:
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_ylabel("")
        _texts.append("removeticks")
    fig.text(0.5, 0.6, " ".join(_texts))

    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
    if fill_figure:
        ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1], which='both')
    plt.show()
    return fig, ax, text
```

`ax.set_position` needs to be after `fig.tight_layout`.
If a figure title is needed, there is no direct way to do it. This unluckily can't be avoided. You need to adapt the `height` parameters manually so that the title fits in the figure, for example with:

```
ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, .9], which='both')
```

Comment: The problem is, when there is a title, this will make it disappear.

Comment: If you want to have a title, you need to do a workaround like: `ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, .9], which='both')`.

Comment: I do not like this hard coded spacing, which is very clumsy when you allow people change the font size and having multi-line title.

Comment: Yep, me neither. But unluckily there is no easy workaround. This is a problem of matplotlib. Imho the easiest workaround is saving the figure as svg, opening it in a svg-Editor like Inkscape, mark the transparent background, delete it and resize the Inkscape document to the figure size. I am sorry, but this is the easiest way to do so.